# const [item1, item2] inside class component (react-native)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I've been working on a React-Native project.

- For `export default function App()` INSERT 1 to 3 (on code) works.
- For `export default class App extends Component` none of the INSERT's works.
- I have to combine them since the modal gives the user the ability to insert text inside the modal and then process the data to console.log and from there use the data.

```
export default class App extends Component {
{/* INSERT 1 before render also gives error */}
render () { 
{/* INSERT 1 */}
const [list, setList] = useState();
    const HandleAddList = () => {
      console.log(list);
{/* INSERT 1 END */}
return (
      <View>
      <Modal
            animationType = {"slide"}
            transparent={false}
            visible={this.state.isVisible}>
              <View  style={styles.ModalContext}>
                <View  style={styles.ModalNavigation}>
              <Text style={[styles.closeText, styles.navText]}
                        onPress={() => {
                          this.displayModal(!this.state.isVisible);
                          }
                        }> Cancel </Text>
              <Text style = {[styles.navHeader, styles.navText] }>
                  New</Text>
                  
                  <Text style={[styles.doneText, styles.navText]}
                        onPress={() => {
                          this.displayModal(!this.state.isVisible);
{/* INSERT 2 */}
                          HandleAddList();
{/* INSERT 2 */}
                          }
                        }> Done </Text>
              </View>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.inputText}
                placeholder='Enter Something...'
{/* INSERT 3 */}
                value = {list}
                onChangeText={text => setList(text)}
{/* INSERT 3 */}
                autoFocus
              />
              </View>
          </Modal>
{/* Rest of the code */}
</View>
{/* const stylesheets etc. */}
```

React-native's documentation told me that I can't use const inside a class component. (https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html).

- INSERT-comments were only for the purpose of the question and testing was done without it...
- All the needed modules was imported from 'react-native'

Any solutions? Would be grateful if someone can help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Hooks on Class Components, it's only a Functional Components' feature. Instead of that you could use this,I'm not pretty sure about some things but you can fix the errors:

```
import styles from './styles.css'

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState();
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);
  
  const HandleAddList = () => {
    console.log(list);
  }
  
  return (
    <View>
      <Modal
        animationType={"slide"}
        transparent={false}
        visible={isVisible}>
        <View style={styles.ModalContext}>
          <View style={styles.ModalNavigation}>
            <Text style={[styles.closeText, styles.navText]}
              onPress={() => {
                setIsVisible(!isVisible);
              }
              }> Cancel </Text>
            <Text style={[styles.navHeader, styles.navText]}>
              New</Text>

            <Text style={[styles.doneText, styles.navText]}
              onPress={() => {
                setIsVisible(!isVisible);
                HandleAddList();
              }
              }> Done </Text>
          </View>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputText}
            placeholder='Enter Something...'
            value={list}
            onChangeText={text => setList(text)}
            autoFocus
          />
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I'm not used to Class Components, but I think this can guide you:

```
    export default class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isVisible: true,
      list: ""
    }
  }

  HandleAddList () {
    console.log(this.state.list);
  }

  render () {

    return (
      <View>
        <Modal
          animationType={"slide"}
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.isVisible}>
          <View style={styles.ModalContext}>
            <View style={styles.ModalNavigation}>
              <Text style={[styles.closeText, styles.navText]}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({...this.state, isVisible: !this.state.isVisible});
                }
                }> Cancel </Text>
              <Text style={[styles.navHeader, styles.navText]}>
                New</Text>
  
              <Text style={[styles.doneText, styles.navText]}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({...this.state, isVisible: !this.state.isVisible});
                  this.HandleAddList();
                }
                }> Done </Text>
            </View>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputText}
              placeholder='Enter Something...'
              value={this.state.list}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ ...this.state, list: text})}
              autoFocus
            />
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    )

  }

}
```

It's so important you read the documentation (https://es.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) by yourself, there's a pair of things here you could fix reading it. It's a pleasure to help anyway, hope this works for you.